# transcriptions of Google Speech Api are not accurate as before

Tags: android, google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google speech API in Arabic language and it was converting speech well before and at accepted accuracy. but the accuracy of the transcriptions becomes not accurate at all suddenly 
I don't know what is wrong. any help in this issue?

Edit:
there is my code to generate the request that sent to the api
I'm using flac audio

```
try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject configData = new JSONObject();
        //config for flac files
        configData.put("encoding", "FLAC");
        configData.put("language_code", "ar-EG");
        configData.put("sample_rate", 16000);
        configData.put("enableAutomaticPunctuation", true);

        JSONObject audioData = new JSONObject();
        audioData.put("content", encodeFileToBase64Binary(filePath));

        body.put("config", configData);
        body.put("audio", audioData);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, body.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=AIzaSyAhYB9C6a8axV7DMYbRluQ3QLa8nXCYL18")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        publishProgress(40);
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String result = response.body().string();
        publishProgress(80);
        Log.d("SpeechApiResult", result);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

private String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(fileName));
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    return new String(encoded);
}
```

Comment: please add your code you have used

Comment: You should share your code!

Comment: I added my code

Comment: _"but the accuracy of the transcriptions becomes not accurate at all suddenly "_ Well, did you change anything in your own app? If not, the problem is at Google's end.

Comment: no I didn't, but what can be the problem at Google's end?

Comment: No idea, as I'm not using the Speech API myself. But the [support page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/support) lists some places to ask or discuss any problems, one being StackOverflow, so somebody relevant might see your question, but there's also the [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-speech-discuss).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this code snippet, I can think of two main causal categories that can affect the transcription quality while using the [Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/).

1. Code:

   - Are you sure that the `configData` object in your code is correctly used to populate [the `RecognitionConfig` object of the client library](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig)? As there is no visibility on the client library implementation, I can’t ascertain it. Make sure you are [importing and using the Google Cloud client library properly by following this guide](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-java).
   - I see that you are using the `enableAutomaticPunctuation` parameter, however [this feature is only available for us-EN language](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation) at the moment. If you are not transcribing from this language, I recommend not using it.
2. Audio:

   - Are you sure the parameters of the `RecognitionConfig` object accurately describe the audio properties of your samples ? Make sure samples are recorded, treated, and programatically set the right way by [following best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices).
   - Another pitfall is the format/encoding confusion. Make sure your samples comply with [supported audio encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding). Besides, converting a sample originally recorded in a lossy format, then converted to a lossless one, will not yield the same transcription quality as with a sample originally recorded in a lossless format.
   - Do your samples all feature the same Arabic language? There are [16 different Arabic languages supported by the Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages). The transcription results will vary greatly in function of this accuracy, and might as well be affected if the recordings comprise local dialects, or slang expressions. Speaker articulation and ambient noises are also important factors.

Following these considerations, I suggest that you try out different ways to record and render samples, and then test their transcription with the API from the [REST reference page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize) or the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/speech%20api/speech/v1/speech.speech.recognize), while making sure the `RecognitionConfig` object is adequatly set for each different sample type.

If following these recommendations doesn't improve the API's results, please note that the Speech-to-text API, as other ML solutions, works with pre-trained prediction models. While these models are constantly improving, the results delivered are still approximate. If you want to help Google improve the API in a particular language, you can opt into [the Data Logging program](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging).